# How to load CrystalReports to ReportViewer in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I searched and apparently, It's possible to do so using the 'ReportSource' property and a ReportDocument but for some reason, I don't have the property.

I installed CrystalReports and opened a new project (WPF CrystalReports). The project come with CrystalReports1.rpt and .cs and the MainWindow with a CrystalReportsViewer inside it. I checked the different properties, but couldn't find anything to fill it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some very old code I have.
I don't think you need to set the name of the datatable since it works with a List.

```
    // DataTable could instead be a collection whose type properties match the report

    ReportDocument rd;
   //  Make the name of the datatable match what the report expects
    dt.TableName = "DataTable1";
    rd = new ReportDocument();
    rd.Load("blaa.rpt");
    rd.SetDataSource(dt);

    rd.Refresh();
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayGroupTree = false;
```

Comment: That's the thing. 'ReportSource' property, doesn't exist apparently.

Comment: Which version of crystal reports are you using? Could be your install and or maybe what you're referencing in your solution.

Comment: It's weird indeed. I just checked again. The file is named: CRforVS_13_0_22. The CrystalReportViewer that I can drag on the form and the one that I can drag on CrystalReport1.cs are not the same for some reason? the one draggable on CrystalReport1.cs have the proprty 'ReportSource' however, I can't call it from the MainWindow which makes it useless. I'm lost

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your comment. The reportviewer is a control. You should have that in a window. This will present the output of  a report. You give it the report by setting it's reportsource. You will also have to call refresh to guarantee the results appear though.